# How to use WebglOverlayView to draw over markers/polygons/etc in Google maps Javascript API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, webgloverlayview

I'm experimenting with the new WebglOverlayView class. I have it drawing basic shapes on the map but would, in some instances, like to draw over other markers/polygons/etc. that I have on the map.

I've tried using the 'renderOrder' property on my BoxGeometry and wasn't able to get that to work.

Is this possible to do? What approach should I take?

The green arrows in the picture below show examples of where I'd like the red rectangle to appear in the forefront.

[image: webgl overlay behind other drawing features]

Comment: This is a current limitation of the WebglOverlayView. Please open a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207 and add a link in another comment here.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194108972

Comment: Thanks for creating the feedback request.

Answer (score 1):

I found a (rather brutal) workaround for this:

- Place an invisible marker on the Map, with a unique title at the coordinate where you want to place the WEBGl-Object
- Find the offset() of this marker using jQuery.
- create a 3d-Object with THREE.js and place it on top of the map according to the offset. (not using Google webglOverlayView)
- Update the offset an position in a loop
- change camera angle and tilt according to the maps camera heading and tilt

maybe that helps.